How to store cart items in session without logged in user and with logged in user in Laravel
I'm using this package "darryldecode/cart" for shopping cart functionality in laravel,
for adding items to cart using this method
  \Cart::session($userID)->add([
            'id' => $productId,
            'name' => $productDetails['name'],
            'price' => $productDetails['price'],
            'quantity' => $productDetails['quantity'],
            'attributes' => [],
            'associatedModel' => $productDetails,
        ]);

but i have doubt if user is not logged in then how we are going to add the items to cart and after user is logged then associate the product with logged in user Id.
Any solution Thanks

you can use a temp user make a cookie with the user token to assign the cart to him and if he login remove the user and reassign to the actual user

I believe if you associate that guest client with a session id, you can later get that guest client session id and associate with the newly logged session id
an example for that:
// Generating a unique identifier for a guest user
$guestSessionId = session()->get('guestSessionId', function() {
   return session()->put('guestSessionId', uniqid('guest_', true));
});

// Adding item to cart for a guest user
\Cart::session($guestSessionId)->add([
    'id' => $productId,
    'name' => $productDetails['name'],
    'price' => $productDetails['price'],
    'quantity' => $productDetails['quantity'],
    'attributes' => [],
    'associatedModel' => $productDetails,
]);

Then you need to handle those sessions and assosiate them with an account
public function loginUser(Request $request)
{
    // here your current auth login, or create one...

    $userId = auth()->id(); // or however you get the logged-in user's ID
    $guestSessionId = session('guestSessionId');

    // Check if there is a cart for the guest user
    if (\Cart::session($guestSessionId)->getContent()->isNotEmpty()) {
        // Merge guest cart into user cart
        $guestCartItems = \Cart::session($guestSessionId)->getContent();
        foreach ($guestCartItems as $item) {
            \Cart::session($userId)->add($item);
        }

        // Clear the guest cart
        \Cart::session($guestSessionId)->clear();

        // Remove the guestSessionId as it's no longer needed
    session()->forget('guestSessionId');
    }
    // everything else of the login logic...
}

I believe this can work in your project, If anything just ask and i'll adapt the response to your actual code.
cheers.
Edit:

Added how you can route it:
I will put it on this file (create it):
app/Http/Middleware/EnsureGuestSessionId.php
And to use it for globally, add it to the $middleware array in
app/Http/Kernel.php.. or for specific routes, add it to the
$routeMiddleware array and apply it to routes in routes/web.php

content of app/Http/Middleware/EnsureGuestSessionId.php:
// app/Http/Middleware/EnsureGuestSessionId.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EnsureGuestSessionId
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $guestSessionId = session()->get('guestSessionId', function() {
            return session()->put('guestSessionId', uniqid('guest_', true));
        });

        // Continue request
        return $next($request);
    }
}


Thanks can you pls let me know where we will call first three lines of your code in laravel $guestSessionId = session()->get('guestSessionId', function() {    return session()->put('guestSessionId', uniqid('guest_', true)); });

@user3653474
I will put it on this file (create it):
app/Http/Middleware/EnsureGuestSessionId.php
And to use it for globally, add it to the $middleware array in app/Http/Kernel.php..
or for specific routes, add it to the $routeMiddleware array and apply it to routes in routes/web.php
